# Is there a simple Program Files/Program Files (x86) directive for C++ in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, path

I am currently hard-coding the path to my application as follows:

```
const char* OriginCopyFile = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\i-cut\\i-cut\\Origin_copy.txt";
```

This application is going to be running in both 32 and 64 systems. How can I detect the path without the file name in order to reuse it with several files and make it portable between architecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the path to your executable, wherever it was installed or even moved later. You can then [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove the executable name (or `strchr()` and friends if you want to support earlier versions than Windows 2000).

Answer (score 5):

[`SHGetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204.aspx) will at least give the path to the program files directory. You'll have to deal with adding the rest of the path and file name.

Comment: You still don't know where the software was actually installed to. All you know is the program files folder, but for all we know it might be installed in C:\i-cut\

Comment: @pezcode: At least according to the title (and the remainder seems to fit with this) he's basically just looking for `Program Files` vs. `Program files (x86)`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use environment variables for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char* programFiles = getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)");   
if (programFiles==NULL)
{
    programFiles = getenv("ProgramFiles");
}

printf(programFiles);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Always use ProgramFiles, never use ProgramFiles(x86) - WOW64 filesystem redirection will take care of the translation.